# Unity: Change button texture from different scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got changing button and `OnClick` script which changes textures of all buttons in the scene. I'd like to change also textures of buttons from a different scene and I've got a problem.

In changing button's inspector is something like this:

[image: Inspector]

The first position refers to the scene in which the change button is located, and it's ok. The second item should refer to a different scene and it's only
"No Function" there. Does anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: There is so many restrictions when you register to button event from the Editor. You need to do that from script instead of the Editor. See **2.Button Component:** from the duplicate which shows how to register to a button event from code.

Comment: Also, you can't change the contents of a different scene: it's not available to make changes to (only one scene exists at a given time, you would have to hold the changed information in a location that persists between scenes, and then change the buttons in the new scene when it loads).